# How to vectorize fitting a normal distribution using scipy and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

I have <s>hundreds of</s> a hundred lists of numbers that I need the mean and standard deviation from (loc and scale in scipy). How can I vectorize `scipy.stats.norm.fit` over a pandas DataFrame to output `(loc, scale)` into two new columns?

I have read that pandas is extremely fast if you can vectorize your equation and apply it to every row or column at the same time. The best I could do was using the `pd.apply` method but that turns out to be slower than iterating over a dictionary of the lists. The following is the `apply` method vs iterating over a dict.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from functools import wraps
from time import time
from scipy.stats import norm


def timing(f):
    """
    Times complete function and prints results
    """

    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kw):
        ts = time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time()
        print(f'Function {f.__name__} took {te-ts:2.6f} seconds')
        return result
    return wrap

# create a dictionary of lists with 100 keys and 1000 values each
a = {str(i): np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000) for i in range(100)}

@timing
def norm_fit(df: DataFrame):

    # rotate the data frame
    df = df.transpose()

    # apply norm.fit accross rows of df save results in new columns
    df[['loc', 'scale']] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(norm.fit(x)), axis=1)

    return df

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = norm_fit(df)


@timing
def for_loop_norm(data: dict):

    # loop through dictionary and fit normal distribution to each list
    for k, v in data.items():
        data[k] = norm.fit(v)

    return data

data = for_loop_norm(a)

@timing
def np_fit(data):

    # convert to numpy array
    data = np.array(list(data.values()))

    # create array of mean values
    means = np.mean(data,axis=1)
    
    #create array of standard deviations
    stds = np.std(data,axis=1)

    return means, stds
means, stds = np_fit(a)
```

Timing the functions results in:

```
Function norm_fit took 0.004000 seconds
Function for_loop_norm took 0.002000 seconds
Function np_fit took 0.001000 seconds
```

I know `pd.apply` functions similar to a for loop but I figured it would at least be as fast as writing an actual `for` loop. Can this be made faster using vectorization?

Comment: what's the connection between `hundreds of lists of numbers` and your dataframe?

Comment: This is a toy example, so instead of my actual data (hundreds of lists of confidential data points) I create a dict with 100 keys and a list of 1000 random numbers for each value.

Comment: "vectorization" is not pixie dust you sprinkle on code. `numpy vectorization` means applying compiled methods to whole arrays, possibly with the help of `axis` parameters.  I'm not familiar with this `fit`, but as long as it only works with one "list/array" at a time, you can't further "vectorize".  Pandas apply is notoriously slow, since it has all the `Series` baggage to apply for each iteration.  I've read that it's "raw" mode is faster.  Also it has a set of stock operations that are relatively fast.

Comment: Iterating on the dict via `data.items()` is probably the best you can do.  If you must iterate, as opposed to working with a whole 2d array, working with lists (or generators like this) is best.

Comment: Fit calls: loc = np.mean()
scale = np.sqrt(((data - loc)**2).mean())

Comment: It seems like I should be able to create a new column of mean() values, then a new column using the “scale” equation as two separate vectorized processes but using pandas core math functions. But again, it’s applied to each row so I don’t know if I can create my own vectorized version of that

Comment: Does `np.array(list(data.values()))` work?  producing a 2d array of floats?

Comment: mean and standard deviation are readily available in pandas. why do you need to use scipy?

Comment: using your suggestion with `np.array`, getting a new array with each arrays mean was trivial and instantaneous but now I have to figure out how to apply the scale equation using the "mean" array and original array. I'm not too familiar with numpy though

Comment: @AtanasAtanasov, good point! The rest of the normal distribution functions I use came from scipy so I've been using it's `fit` function up til now. I just tested creating columns with pd.mean() and pd.std() and the for loop is still faster which surprised me. Almost twice as fast on larger arrays (100,000 rows)

Comment: dataframes have a lot of overhead. I am not too surprised that iterating through dictionary is fast. I am sure in numpy there are both functions for mean and std

Comment: @hpaulj, I realized numpy could apply mean and std across axis=1 and this is twice as fast now thank you. Added numpy function to question (would this be considered vectorized at this point?)

Comment: I would consider it vectorized yes